# Can I Delete an Activity from getstream.io using fields other than Id and ForeignId?

Tags: c#, getstream-io

I am a beginner in getstream.io. I want to delete an activity by **actor, verb and object**. Is there any way of doing it . I don't want to use there two ways due to my code restrictions:

```
userFeed1.RemoveActivity("post:42", true);
userFeed1.RemoveActivity("e561de8f-00f1-11e4-b400-0cc47a024be0");
```

Is there any way to get a single activity without using activity id because we don't know what Id has been assigned to my activity.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1):

When adding activities, you should include a foreign_id that matches an id in your app, as well as a time field. This way, you can better handle your deletes. We do not have a way to delete an activity by any of the fields you've specified.